# Can I insert ("squeeze in") a row in a table and increase remaining values after the inserted row with one query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I wonder if I can insert a row in a table and increase all remaining values after the inserted row?

Take look at the sample table below:

```
+----+----------+-----------+ 
| id | position | data      |
+----+----------+-----------+ 
| 1  |  1       | Paris     |
| 2  |  2       | London    |
| 3  |  3       | Berlin    |
| 4  |  4       | Madrid    |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

The `id` column is the primary key. The `position` column is used to sort the data in custom order. I now wonder if it's possible to create an INSERT/UPDATE-query in MySQL to "sqeeze in" a new city in the table, i.e. the position values need to be increased after the insert, like this:

```
+----+----------+-----------+ 
| id | position | data      |
+----+----------+-----------+ 
| 1  |  1       | Paris     |
| 2  |  2       | London    |
| 5  |  3       | New York  |  <-- inserted row... positions after are increased
| 3  |  4       | Berlin    |  <-- position +1
| 4  |  5       | Madrid    |  <-- position +1
+----+----------+-----------+
```

I first thought that I solve this in PHP by modifying each row in a loop. But I hope I can solve this with one single INSERT-query. Is that possible?

```
INSERT INTO table SET position=3, data="New York" {AND INCREASE THE REST of postion}
```

Comment: What level of understanding do you have of how tables are implemented in modern (post-1995) RDBMS (i.e. post-dBase)? I'm asking so I can frame my answer appropriately.

Comment: See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65517250/creating-specific-size

Comment: 'hope I can solve this with one single INSERT-query. Is that possible' - no it isn't, if you have a working method in PHP just go with that.

Comment: @Strawberry Given how the OP worded their question it gives me the impression they aren't familiar with how tables are physically stored on-disk - there's no point me giving an answer that explains why "inserting" a record in-between two others _is not a thing_ when the audience isn't familiar with paging, B-trees, clustered indexes, et cetera. Fortunately I eventually found a way to word my answer that meant I could skip that topic entirely.

Comment: See. It wasn't so hard :-) (although a transaction is not required here)

Comment: @Strawberry How is a transaction not required? The OP needs to run **two** separate DML statements.

Comment: @Dai Thinking about it a bit more, a transaction is probably a better idea... but just for fun... https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tF2jJ4y8tcjPXCPNNEe2EY/0

Comment: @Strawberry ah, I didn’t know about `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, TIL! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rows in tables are not physically stored in-order of their primary-key values (the real answer, as ever, is "it's complicated" - I'll be happy to go into detail on this point if you like).

But w.r.t. your question, the solution is straightforward:

```
SET @insertAtPosition = 3;
SET @insertData = 'New York';

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE tbl SET Position = Position + 1 WHERE Position >= @insertAtPosition;

INSERT INTO tbl ( Position, Data ) VALUES ( @insertAtPosition, @insertData );

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

---

Note that the use of `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION` is important so that the `Position` values won't be updated without a new row being successfully inserted - if the `INSERT` (or the `UPDATE`) fails for whatever reason, then the `Position` values will be unchanged, as though the attempt was never made.